# "while True:" loop returns nothing after one cycle

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-3.5

Here's the problem: my while loop doesn't repeat AT ALL, it just returns a blank line in the Python Launcher and doesn't carry on the code, i added a print function at the end to check if it did just skip.
I used several ways of getting the code to repeat, such as `While True:` and `While 0 == 0` so i have started to think there is a problem somewhere else in the code. The code in question is:

```
while True:
 while i <= dice_amount:
   dice_output = random.randint(0,dice_range)
   print("dice number ", i, " is ", dice_output)
   i +=1
 while input_answer == "unknown":
   input_answer = input("would you like to throw the dice again? Y/N")
   if input_answer == "N":
    time.sleep(2)
    os.exit
   elif input_answer != "Y":
    input_answer = "unknown"

print("code is broken") #to see if code just skips loop
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYxOQ.png) is what happens when i try to repeat
I would much appreciate the help and I'd just like to say I'm new to coding so I know it may not be optimised, however a comment saying how i could optimise it would be helpful.

At the start the variables are defined as such:

```
dice_amount = int(input("how many times would you like to roll the dice?"))
dice_range = int(input("how many numbers would you like on the dice?"))
input_answer = "unknown"
i = 1
```

Comment: Where are `i`, `dice_amount` and `input_answer` defined? What are their values before the loops?

Comment: sorry, edited my question to show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set i to one after "while True", and set input_answer to "unknown" before the second inner loop. Corrected code:

```
while True:
 i = 1
 while i <= dice_amount:
   dice_output = random.randint(0,dice_range)
   print("dice number ", i, " is ", dice_output)
   i +=1
 input_answer = "unknown"
 while input_answer == "unknown":
   input_answer = input("would you like to throw the dice again? Y/N")
   if input_answer == "N":
    time.sleep(2)
    os.exit
   elif input_answer != "Y":
    input_answer = "unknown"

print("code is broken") #to see if code just skips loop
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that to my question, its at the bottom now

Comment: i don't see how this'll help, i do both of these before this whole chunk of code?

Comment: The issue is if you reroll. Neither of the inner loops will run again if you choose to reroll, since `i` is already greater than `dice_amount` and `input_answer` is already `"Y"`. Iniitializing them within the `while True` loop fixes that.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks, i've changed the code to put i to 1 when Y is entered and made a new variable input_known to remove the problem. BTW as i'm knew to this, if there's now a new issue should i create a new question

Comment: i removed the new variable and changed it to an infinite loop (in my answer)

Comment: Generally speaking, if it's a new question, it should be asked separately. If it's something small enough to not warrant a new question, then you should update your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally realized the problem, after reading the other comments and answers I came up with this fix. First of all I realized I didn't need to use the input_answer if none of the answers were Y or N, i just made it a repeating loop and if the were neither Y or N it just repeated the question, Y breaks the loop and N ends the program. if the reply was Y i added i = 1 so that it would repeat.

Here's the fixed code:

```
import random
import time
dice_amount = int(input("how many times would you like to roll the dice?"))
dice_range = int(input("how many numbers would you like on the dice?"))
i = 1

while True:
 while i <= dice_amount:
   dice_output = random.randint(0,dice_range)
   print("dice number ", i, " is ", dice_output)
   i +=1
 while True:
   input_answer = input("would you like to throw the dice again? Y/N")
   if input_answer == "N":
    time.sleep(2)
    os.exit
   elif input_answer == "Y":
    i = 1
    break
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to get the break to work so that it asks how many number etc. again however this isn't what i wanted so I would consider this a sufficient answer. PS. please feel free to leave a comment on this answer saying how to get it to ask the questions again